# Representative sample test XML file

Tags: xml, sample-data, test-data

I'm looking for a somewhat representative sample test XML file for a typical application. It should contain all typical XML features, such as

- Elements with and without attributes
- Text (both structured and unstructured)
- Namespaces
- CDATA
- DTD / Entity declarations
- Comments
- Processing instructions

And some half-sensible data of around 50kb or more. Does anyone know such a sample document? It should have a license compatible with Apache 2.0 or similar

Comment: See W3C [XML Test Suite](http://www.w3.org/XML/Test/)

Comment: Thanks @empo, seems obvious at first sight. But they're all very small... I don't need to test XML itself, but an XML API...

Comment: Sorry probably I'm missing the main question. I've provided the link only as possible source of sample files which you can use to create your "sample test XML file".

Comment: @empo, I see. Well, I'm too lazy for that, that's why I asked :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if in general is possible to write a **single** test file containing any XML feature.

Comment: one useful post on XMl you can find [here http://bay-six.blogspot.in](http://bay-six.blogspot.in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can have a look at XSL examples like [**this**](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/xml/guide/xslexample.html) involving either XML with DTD and XSL. All three are XML documents each one with an (almost) full set of XML features.
- For other basic documents involving namespace and attributes you might be interested in looking at the W3C [XSL test suite](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/TestSuite/). For example, you can directly download a [.fo basic file](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/TestSuite/contrib/FOP/basic1.fo) from FOP vendor.
- Other, obvious, place to gather useful examples is at the various tutarials of W3School like in [DTD examples](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_examples.asp), [SOAP examples](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_example.asp), [XML CData examples](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) and so on

Comment: Thanks for those links. I'm not sure about the license of w3school documents, but there are some representative samples among them, which I can anonymise...