# Is XML semi structured data?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Can somebody explain me why XML is an semi structured data? Why it cannot be a structured data?
If it is semi structure data , can you please explain me below XML example, so it would be very helpful.

```
<Node>
    <FirstName>VITTHAL</FirstName>
    <LastName>MUGULI</LastName>
</Node>
```

Comment: The first paragraph at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-structured_data answers your question.

Comment: What is there to "explain" about your XML example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representative sample test XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999739/representative-sample-test-xml-file)

Comment: I have the same question. Maybe it's considered semi structured because you can add any tag to it and the tags ar not known in advance. So you can't imagine a table (like relational model) with specific columns in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Semi structure data is a set of documents on the web which contain hyperlinks to other document and it cannot be modeled in natural relational data model because the pattern of hyperlinks is not regular across documents.